# ng serve command prompting error 549 in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have tried with all given solutions like updating *angular/cli* and even uninstalling and reinstalling *node/npm*. I can create new project and it works as expected but when I am trying run ng serve command on my existing project it is showing me below error. Please help to resolve this.

> module.js:549
>           throw error;
>           ^
>           Error: Cannot find module './template'
>               at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>               at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>               at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>               at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>               at Object. (E:\Project\Nitesh\AngularMergedCode\AngularDemo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\utils\index.js:19:10)
>               at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>               at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>               at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>               at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>               at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>           PS E:\Project\Nitesh\AngularMergedCode\AngularDemo> npm update
>           PS E:\Project\Nitesh\AngularMergedCode\AngularDemo> ng serve

Package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "offica-replica",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.9",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.9.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "template": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your `package.json` file.

Comment: I have shared the file. @SyedAliTaqi

Comment: as you said, the error comes on existing project and new projects runs fine. Did you follow the correct path while migrating your old project to Angular 6? you can check the guide [here](https://update.angular.io/).

Comment: have you try to run npm install @GarimaKinra

Comment: The project was running fine earlier but once the vscode editor got crash down after which the project stopped compiling.Though i m not sure whether this is the reason or not.So, I don't think  migration could be the issue.Please suggest.@Syed Ali Taqi

Comment: Yes,I have It shows me up to date in 11s message along with this error code @MuhammedAlbarmawi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem, It was a missing module problem so i need to perform these 2 steps:

1.Remove node_modules folder from project directory.

2. Run command npm install (This will reinstall all missing modules)

   After this ng serve command works fine.